# AngularJS - Test if a string matches a route

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way in angular, when given the following route

```
.when('/customer/:customerId', {
    templateUrl: 'views/summary.tpl.html',
    controller: 'SummaryController'
})
```

to be able to test if a string matches that route?

For example with the string

```
'/customer/3'
```

is there a function in angular that I can call to determine if the route matches a route or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over all defined routes and check if there is a match:

```
angular.forEach($route.routes, function(route) {        
    if(route.regexp.exec(myURL)){
        match = true;
    }        
})
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeA6m/3/).

Comment: This is very interesting. Do you know if it is documented or not (couldn't find it in the docs with a quick search)?

Comment: I did not saw it in the docs. I found it here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L469

Answer (score 1):

It is a good question, which I too have tackled with. You can look for inspiration here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2274

Unfortunately, that means you'd have to cobble something together by using some mocking. There is not a solve-it-all function, sadly. Or you can use the state provider itself and try changing state, based on url, and then check if you are in the expected state.